# Как отправить несколько файлов (изображений) в одном сообщении?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Вот как я пытался это реализовать.

Пример:

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
@bot.command()
async def command(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
   await ctx.message.delete()
   await channel.send(
   file=discord.File(r'H:\File1.png',
   file=discord.File(r'H:\File2.png')))
```

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Вроде бы так делать нельзя. Вариант отправить все двумя сообщениями вам не подходит?

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно именно 2 изображения в одном сообщении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await send(content=None, *, tts=False, embed=None, embeds=None, file=None, files=None, stickers=None, delete_after=None, nonce=None, allowed_mentions=None, reference=None, mention_author=None, view=None, suppress_embeds=False)
```

Подробнее в документации [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send).

Вместо `file` используйте `files` и список файлов, которые хотите отправить. Также стоит отметить, что максимальное кол-во файлов в список - 10.

В конце концов, если данный вариант вам не подходит, вы можете отправить файлы разными сообщениями.

Comment: Всё работает так, как нужно. Спасибо!